# How should parameter to function be given when AddressOf used?

Tags: .net, multithreading

See the following code:

```
Public Sub MyFunction1(ByVal CodeNo As Integer)

    Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf MyFunction2)
    thread.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub MyFunction2(ByVal CodeNo As Integer)

    Debug.Print CodeNo

End Sub
```

How should a parameter value be supplied to `MyFunction2`?

Why is the compiler letting this compile and execute with `CodeNo` being set to `0`?

Answer (score 1):

It's compiling because you haven't got Option Strict on. If you turn on Option Strict (which IMO you should pretty much always do) it won't compile - your function isn't compatible with either `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart`. If you change the parameter type to `Object` however, it's fine - and you can a value into `Start` which will then be passed to the function. Short but complete example:

```
Option Strict On

Imports System
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf Foo)
        thread.Start("hello")
        thread.Join()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub Foo(ByVal value As Object)
        Console.WriteLine(value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I didn't have to change the parameter type to `Object`. (I still don't have `Option Strict` on.)

Comment: @CJ7: I used `Thread.Join` so that the program wouldn't exit before the new thread got a chance to run. And you *would* have to change the parameter type to Object if you turned Option Strict on, which I strongly recommend you should.